# PHP and Javascript System to count that I adds +1 to random

Tags: php, count, char

I created a system in php and javascript in which a user can enter a certain number of characters (5) and automatically update a cell in a db in mysql, but there is a problem ... every now and then the system will not count +2 instead of +1, I'll post the code

```
$sql=mysql_query("select * from bare");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
//se voglio fare sanitizer $name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
$id= $row['id'];
$cab=$row['cab'];
$qty=$row['qty'];
//echo "$id $cab $qty <br/>";

if(isset($_POST['submitbar']))
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    {   
         if( $name == $cab) {
            echo '<p>';
            $nqty = $qty+1;
            mysql_query("UPDATE bare SET qty = $nqty WHERE cab = '$cab'");
            echo "Hai aggiunto 1 elemento a $cab. Ora $cab vale $nqty";
            echo '</p>';
        } else {
    //echo '<p>Non corrisponde a nessun codice a barre nel database<p>';    

    }
}
}

?>
<h1>Aggiorna le quantit&agrave; utilizzando il Barcode</h1>
<form id="form" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
   <input id="seleziona" type="text" name="name"><br>
   <input type="submit" name="submitbar" value="Invia"><br>
</form>
<!--<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('input').charCount(25);
});
</script> -->
<script type="text/javascript">
//seleziona input automatico
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#seleziona').jqEasyCounter();

});
</script>
<script>
//invio automatico
    $("#seleziona").keyup(function(){
         if($(this).val().length == 5)
            $('#form :submit').click();
    })
</script>
```

I **think** that problem is

```
$nqty = $qty+1;
```

because variable $nqty remains in memory...

Answer (score 0):

The general approach to this in a stateless system like PHP is to let the database handle atomic increments, e.g. modifying the statement to:

```
UPDATE bare SET qty = qty + $nqty WHERE cab = '$cab'
```

In this case, $nqty would be the number to add to 'qty' and the database would ensure it happens atomically, to avoid the [read-modify-write](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read_modify_write) race condition.

Additionally, it is poor practice to insert variables directly into an sql string (due to [sql injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sql_injection)). Instead use [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement).

Comment: Thanks for the corrections but the problem still persists: in both cases, when I copy and paste a string of five after one or two entries, even after waiting 3 seconds, the system will not count +2 ... is random (or at least it seems)

I think we should make a rule to
$nqty = $row['qty'] + 1;
or kill the variable at the end if
is there a way?

Comment: The problem is that you're loading the value and doing the addition within PHP. You *have* to do it at the database where it can guarantee only one thread at a time will be doing the read-modify-write. That is, the 'qty = qty + 1' has to be inside your SQL query, not inside your PHP code.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, I would suggest the following :

```
    $name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT qty FROM bare WHERE cab = '$name'");
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($sql);

    if(isset($_POST['submitbar']) && $row)  {
        $nqty = $row['qty'] + 1;
        $name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
        mysql_query("UPDATE bare SET qty = qty + 1 WHERE cab = '$name'");
        echo "<p>Hai aggiunto 1 elemento a $name. Ora $name vale $nqty</p>";
    }
```

That would :

1. Limit the number of iterations in your code
2. Update the same rows
3. Display the same information

(*in case of concurrent updates, the UI display might not be 100% correct, however the backend data should be*)

As a side note -because this is not your question- i would suggest you search *MVC* term, as it is a good practice to separate database, php logic and html display. Which you are not doing, but it might just be a quick & dirty / non production code :-)

EDIT: in addition to good advice from drobert about atomicity and prepared statements, which would require  to use PDO mysql (worth the check in your `phpinfo()`).

Comment: Thanks for the corrections but the problem still persists: in both cases, when I copy and paste a string of five after one or two entries, even after waiting 3 seconds, the system will not count +2 ... is random (or at least it seems) I think we should make a rule to $nqty = $row['qty'] + 1; or kill the variable at the end if is there a way?

Comment: Are you sure that when +2 occurs, it is upon only 1 http request ? Which would confirm this is a server side issue indeed. Otherwise, the +2 might occur only because for some reason, 2 http requests are made. (even if it looks like one request). Can you setup firebug or similar debugger in persist mode to confirm ?

Comment: In chrome, you can use the developer tools. When logging all requests (the 'record' like button), can you see unwanted requests ?

Comment: I don't understand where i find this feature but i've recorded a video (now i use code from Pandaiolo) -> watch http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YPbPA1NcmFw

Comment: It is the 5h button on the bottom from the left. It will let you see how much requests are done. From the video it is not very clear if there is a 1/1 ratio between requests and increments.